# ssrs call report in a loop (subreport?)

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with the **area** as Parameter. For each area, I want to call the report with some grouping. I want to display this report for each area side by side. 
It should look like this:

```
areaNo1                                areaNo2
dealerNr1 - dealerName1 - colA - colB  dealerNr3 - dealerName3 - colA - colB
dealerNr2 - dealerName2 - colA - colB  dealerNr4 - dealerName4 - colA - colB
                          sum  - sum                             sum    sum
```

What is the best way to achieve this? 
The area is dynamically (select distinct area from....)! I thought to solve this with a subreport in a loop, but no idea how.

thx ©a-x-i

Comment: A grouped table sending a parameter to the sub report should do it. Have the sub report accept the area param from the text box in the main reports table that is grouped by Area.

Comment: I agree with Snowlockk. Create a sub report that accepts a single area as a parameter. Then create a report that has a dataset (dsAreas) containing a list of the areas you need. If you want a single column stack list then just create a table that uses dsAreas as it's datasource and add the subreport into the single cell. If you need to have it two columns wide then you might have to use a matrix and and pass the parameter to the subreport as an expression. Not sure how to form the expression now but if you don't get anywhere, comment here and I'll have a think about it when I'm not as busy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no a concept of a defined loop structure within SSRS.  The closest you can come is the row by row/col by col processing when populating a tablix/matrix.

To achieve printing side by side, you can put your report in a subreport container in a matrix using the area as the column group.  I've used a tablix to accomplish similar things.  However, there will likely be a number of issues this causes; performance and pagination are the items that come to mind first.

SSRS is best suited for making structured reports that may end up printed.  What you are describing will not scale to the printed page very well and I don't think SSRS will make a good final solution.  You may get it work, but I expect it will be slow, fragile and high maintenance.